# ActiveMQ JDBC persistence trouble: ACTIVEMQ_MSGS is always empty

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

everybody!

I'm trying to use JDBC persistence with ActiveMQ. So, when producer sends message, it should be saved into ACTIVEMQ_MSGS table by default. But when I check this table, it's always empty. I don't understand where the trouble is.

Here is Spring XML config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd        
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
            http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
          http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
        " >


        <bean 
                id="producer"
                class="com.jmsexamples.Producer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />  
        </bean>

        <bean id="jdbc_ds" 
                    class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ActiveMq?relaxAutoCommit=true" />
            <property name="user" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

      <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

      <amq:queue id="queue" physicalName="message.queue" />

  <amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="true">
        <amq:persistenceAdapter>
            <amq:jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#jdbc_ds"/>
        </amq:persistenceAdapter>    
        <amq:transportConnectors>
          <amq:transportConnector uri="vm://localhost:61616" />
        </amq:transportConnectors> 
      </amq:broker>
```

UPD producer code:

```
public class Producer{

    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private Destination dest;

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory conFact){
        this.connectionFactory = conFact;   
    }

    public void sendMessage(){

        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {

            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("roman", "sawawluha");
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            dest = new ActiveMQQueue("message.queue");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(dest);
      for(int i=0;i<10; i++)
      {         
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();

              message.setText("This is text message!");
              producer.send(message);
      }
        } catch(JMSException  e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
      try {
              session.close();
              connection.close();
                System.out.println("closing");
      } catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you also reading from the queue?

Comment: And are you sending with a MessageProducer that uses PERSISTENT message delivery.

Comment: well, I only send messages, without consumers. I have only producer (code attached to old message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a different url in the connection factory and the broker transport.
You should probably have tcp://localhost:61616 at both places.

There should be some exception around non the less

Comment: It doesn't work when transportConnector and brokerURL are both tcp://localhost:61616. It throws "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" exception. Irony is that in my case (when it differs) messages are really sending, because I can see message queue in JBoss Fuse web-console

Comment: ok, then you have a broker defined elsewhere listening to tcp port 61616. That broker is likely dealing with the messages and your JDBC persisted broker is idle. The `<amq:broker .. ` element creates the broker. If you have Fuse ESB you probably have another one installed as an OSGI bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Petter said that JDBC broker is idle, I've simply restarted Fuse, changed URL's to tcp://localhost:61616, and now my producer uses correct broker. Thanks!